# How was Google.com made?

Tags: c, perl, web-applications, cgi

I'm very curious as to what programming languages were used to make Google. In the early days, Larry Page and Sergey Brin tried to licence their search algorithm to Yahoo. What I would love to know is what language(s) was the software first written in?

I have a feeling it was C or perl (CGI), anyone know for sure?

Thank you in advance

Anyone know the database they used too?

Comment: Google is based on "PigeonRank TM" as they say themselves: http://www.google.com/technology/pigeonrank.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Google search engine was originally called [BackRub](http://web.archive.org/web/19971210065425/backrub.stanford.edu/backrub.html) and was written in Java and Python.  To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Google):

> BackRub is written in Java and Python and runs on several Sun Ultras and Intel Pentiums running Linux. The primary database is kept on an Sun Ultra II with 28GB of disk. Scott Hassan and Alan Steremberg have provided a great deal of very talented implementation help. Sergey Brin has also been very involved and deserves many thanks.
>   -Larry Page page@cs.stanford.edu

Also interesting is [Google's Corporate History](http://www.google.com/corporate/history.html) page, though it doesn't talk as much about the original software.